# How to establish the distributive property of sum notation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Establish the following property of sum notation:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_i+b_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i + \sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i$$

I have tried in two ways. My first try uses recursive induction:

> $$\sum_{i=1}^{1}(a_i+b_i) = a_1+b_1 = \sum_{i=1}^{1}a_i+\sum_{i=1}^{1}b_i$$
>
> Now, assuming $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_i+b_i)$ is true for $i \le n$, we define
>
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(a_i+b_i) &= \sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_i+b_i) + (a_{n+1}+b_{n+1}) \\
> &= \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i+ \sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i+a_{n+1}+b_{n+1} \\
> &= \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}a_i+\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}b_i \\
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> hence it is true for $i=1$, and if it's true for $k$ then it's true for $k+1$, so it is true for all positive integers.

My second try:

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_i+b_i) &= (a_1+b_1) + \ldots + (a_n+b_n) \\
> &= (a_1 + \ldots + a_n)+(b_1 + \ldots + b_n) \\
> &= \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i+\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i
> \end{align}
> $$

What is the right way to establish the above equation? My first try, my second, both, or neither?

Comment: Hi: $\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i + b_i)$ is supposed to mean "sum" and not "product" as you seem to write in many places in your OP.

Comment: Hi, i don't know where i put product everything seems ok

Comment: You have typos in the second way, some $+$'s missing. If we write it the right way, then your second approach is the informal reason that the equality holds, while your first way gives a more formal argument.

Comment: You have a typo in your base case: $a_1+a_1$ should be $a_1+b_1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seond try is more intuitive, but by its use of "..." is not *really* a proof. The first version is thus preferable (by far, in my opinion).

Comment: nothing wrong with it?

Comment: There are some things wrong. For example, it does not make sense to say that $\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i+b_i)$ is true for $i\ge 1$. Two errors. The sum is an *expression*, it cannot be true or false. And you meant for some $n\ge 1$.  At the end of that argument there is confusion, $i=1$, then mention of mysterious $k$. It really should have been $\sum_{i=1}^k$, and then we do the $k+1$ case, but $n$, $n+1$ is OK.

Answer (score 0):

They both can work, since the sum is on finite numbers. It always hold!

Comment: How are any of them a formal proof? The first one doesn't use the intermediate elements (between ```i=0``` and ```i=n+1```), while the second suffers from the same issue using ```...```. Could you please clarify? Thanks!